# No pictures are showing up in Facebook when I post the link to my site

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, facebook, haml

MY website is Hidden for Privacy. I am trying to get a photo to show up when I post my link to my facebook, but I had all of my pictures in my CSS rather than in the HTML because it is a parallax site. Now I then searched what Facebook looks for with the pictures it posts and was given HTML which I then switched to haml. I did have to hide the picture simply because I can't have it displayed on the page when I already have something displayed.

My code is...

```
.hidden
  = link_to(image_tag("/assets/WB_small.jpg", :alt => "logo"), "/")
```

The HTML output is...

```
<div class='hidden'>
      <a href="/"><img alt="logo" src="/assets/WB_small.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
```

Has anyone dealt with something like this before or knows a specific way to make Facebook grab a photo, but not display it on the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<head>
<meta property='og:image' content='image.jpg'/>
</head>
```

Comment: This fixed my favicon issue as well it seems. I have no idea why or how. Though the image I put in there won't work with Facebook, but it does pull the other image off the site.